# How to attach PostgreSQL tables / databases in email and send them to recipient?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, web-applications, cron

Group mates and I are making a web app with Typescript / Javascript, and will store user-generated data in PostgreSQL.

I've written a Typescript module to send regular emails by cron.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cron = require('node-cron');

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });

function buildDate() {
    let date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let day = ("0" + date.getDay()).slice(-2);
    let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

}

cron.schedule("00 00 00 * * *", function () {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: '465',
        auth: {
            service: 'gmail',
            user: process.env.senderEmail,
            pass: process.env.senderPassword,
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.senderEmail,
        to: 'fakename@gmail.com',
        subject: 'News letter - ' + buildDate(),
        html: '<h1> Todays topics include ..</h1>',
        text: 'hello world',
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error: string, info: any) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
        }
    })

});
```

My question is: 1. how to auto-generate tables / database from PostgreSQL? 2. How to attach the tables / database in the email?

The format can be plain text, csv, or pdf. Take making a report on the number of registered users every week as an example:

```
import * as Knex from "knex";

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
    return await knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('users',(table)=>{
        table.increments();
        table.string('username').unique;
        table.string('email').unique;
        table.string('password');
        table.timestamps(false, true);
    })
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
    return await knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('users');
}
```

Grateful if you could help :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a weird requirement, but the best way to generate a text representation of a PostgreSQL database or parts thereof (such as a single table) is to call the `pg_dump` executable with the appropriate arguments.

This utility generates an SQL script that will restore the exported parts of the database when you feed it to the `psql` command line client.

Comment: May I know how weird it is? What are the common ways to deliver user evaluation target audience?

Comment: It must be my stupidity. I have never heard of "user evaluation target audience".

Comment: my bad. it's 'to deliver user evaluation result to target audience'.